# C# Winforms: Customize DataGridView selected gridcolor

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, colors, grid

I have `DataGridView` which has 3 columns and 3 rows. If user selects one row, I want to make the grids of that row to change color. I'm completely new to C# and I cant figure out how can I achieve my goal. Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Guys, I don't need to change the fore or back color of the cell. I need to change the color of gridlines (borders). Appreciate your tries  anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are asking about modifying the appearance of the cells' **GridLines** and doing it **individually**.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewadvancedborderstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this **is** possible. However it seems to involve a real big effort. You would need to subclass the `DataGridview` and modify the example code extensively to work dynamically. After toying with it for a while I decided, that it isn't worth it. I suggest going for one of the other ways to mark the selection. (Or gain a lot of rep and put a bounty on it..)

Comment: I agree, this is not worth it. And this is kind of unorthodox thing I suppose, thanks for your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the properties of the `DataGridView` class, you have the option to set the grid color in the `DataGridView.GridColor` property.

> Gets or sets the color of the grid lines separating the cells of the DataGridView.

Example below:

```
dataGridView1.GridColor = SystemColors.ActiveBorder;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I wanted. I want GridColor to change, not the BackColor.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it using DataGridView.GridColor property. This will change the color of the grid lines.
See the link - [DataGridView.GridColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.gridcolor(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 dataGridView1.GridColor = SystemColors.Blue;
```

This will change every line in the grid. Can you specify what exactly of the row you want to change? I presume you want only the lines of the row. If you want to change only the row lines color, than you can use the following code:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
```

Below you can see it used in CellClick event on the row:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
    if (dgv == null)
        return;
    if (dgv.CurrentRow.Selected)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I want to hide the horizontal lines which are around my selected row and I want to make the vertical lines of that row to change color. Is this even possible in `Winforms`?

Comment: If you want to hide the lines use this code - dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None. But I don't think that you can change only the horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridViewRow dgRow = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
dgRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
dgRow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Comment: Please add explanation and context to your code snippet.